# wpa_supplicant :not found

Tags: wifi, wpa-supplicant

I entered in /etc/network/interfaces file

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback and

the i tried ifconfig it showing

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 8A:B8:53:87:09:2A
inet6 addr: fe80::88b8:53ff:fe87:92a/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:360 (360.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp

**ifconfig: SIOCGIFFLAGS: No such device**

then i tried this ifconfig wlan0 it shows the error:

ifconfig: wlan0: error fetching interface information: Device not found

in the bootup logs i observed:

Starting network: [    6.178148] ip (252) used greatest stack depth: 5756 bytes left
/bin/sh: wpa_supplicant: not found
FAIL

How to debug this ?

Comment: Looks like a memory-related kernel message got into the middle of the network startup message from boot-up scripts. It looks like your system might be low on RAM memory. Which distribution are you using, and how much RAM your system has?

Comment: Debian distribution and RAM is 1gb

Answer (score 0):

https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/ch03s04.en.html has the current minimum requirements for Debian 10. (The link is for the x86_64 version, but the numbers for the 32-bit version are the same.)

The minimum values (256 MiB for without GUI, 512 MiB with GUI) assume a pretty minimalist installation, so depending on what packages you have chosen, your RAM might already be pretty fully in use.

> It is possible to run a graphical desktop environment on older or low-end systems, but in that case it is recommended to install a window manager that is less resource-hungry than those of the GNOME or KDE Plasma desktop environments; alternatives include xfce4, icewm and wmaker, but there are others to choose from.

Comment: Processor is ARM Cortex-A7,

Comment: Hi,Processor is ARM Cortex-A7,RAM 1gb,and distribution is Debian i was created rootfs using buildroot and i enabled wpa supplicant  in buildroot,wpa_suplicant file created,i entered auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp in  /etc/network/interfaces   after booting the above error is showing .How to debug this?

Comment: please look in to my edited question

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much at all about buildroot.