# /bin/sh: wpa_supplicant: not found

Tags: wifi, wpa-supplicant, root-filesystem, buildroot

I entered in `/etc/network/interfaces` file

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
```

Then i tried `ifconfig`. It's showing

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 8A:B8:53:87:09:2A  
          inet6 addr: fe80::88b8:53ff:fe87:92a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:360 (360.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

ifconfig: SIOCGIFFLAGS: No such device
```

Then I tried `ifconfig wlan0`, but it shows the error:

```
ifconfig: wlan0: error fetching interface information: Device not found
```

In the bootup logs I observed:

```
Starting network: [    6.178148] ip (252) used greatest stack depth: 5756 bytes left
/bin/sh: wpa_supplicant: not found
FAIL
```

How to debug this ?

Comment: install wpa supplicant first ```apt or yum install wpasupplicant```

Comment: my rootfs is minimal because of size constraint  there is no apt folder.

Comment: Please use [the appropriate formatting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help) for console input/output and file content. I tried to edit your post to make it more readable, but the order of some parts seemed off, so you will need to look over it.

Comment: Repost of [wpa\_supplicant :not found](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/596448/wpa-supplicant-not-found)?